# Unique issue with a BitLocker cloned partition

Tags: windows, bitlocker, disk-cloning

I have a unique problem for which I am seeking a solution. I have a laptop which originally had a 256GB M.2 NVMe SSD. I upgraded the drive to a 1TB model, and used MiniTool partition wizard to clone the older drive into the new one. The cloned drive worked fine and was functional. What I was unaware of that BitLocker was enabled and during the cloning process the tool showed no warning to disable BitLocker

Now one day I had to reinstall Windows freshly and the situation I am now in is that the other partition with all my useful data is encrypted with BitLocker. I tried all the recovery keys that were synced online with my Microsoft account but none of them work. What I am wondering is that why those recovery keys do not work and if a new key was generated during the cloning process why was it not synced online.

Is there something I can do in this matter to access the encrypted partition and recover my data?

Looking forwards to your suggestions.

Comment: Do you still have the original SSD intact?

Comment: The original SSD is still there, but I formatted it.

Comment: "What I am wondering is if a new key was generated during the cloning process why was it not synced online." - If this happened, then you were presented that it was happening, but MiniTool wouldn't have done it.  So if I understand the problem, you are stuck at a prompt, asking for your Recovery key?

Comment: @Ramhound It used to be like this. But I decided then to format the OS partition and install Windows 10 again. The other partition I had is locked and is asking for the recovery key.